# AjaxForm на modx - перезагружает страницу

Tags: jquery, ajax, modx, formit

Реализую AjaxForm через Formit на modx. При нажатии кнопки "отправить" страница перезагружается, чего делать не должна(при этом данные отправляются на почту корректно) В консоли ошибка

```
VM72735 default.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (VM72735 default.js:16)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (VM72729 jquery.js:4641)
    at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (VM72729 jquery.js:4309)
```

На форумах пишут про ошибки при подключении библиотек: на сайте в header  уже подключена библиотека jquery 1.11.1. Перед закрывающим body Ajax вставляет свои ссылки таким образом:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/components/minifyx/cache/scripts_a810106fda.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/components/ajaxform/js/default.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">AjaxForm.initialize({"assetsUrl":"\/assets\/components\/ajaxform\/","actionUrl":"\/assets\/components\/ajaxform\/action.php","closeMessage":"\u0437\u0430\u043a\u0440\u044b\u0442\u044c \u0432\u0441\u0435","formSelector":"form.ajax_form","pageId":11});</script>
```

Подскажите в чем может быть ошибка, в какую сторону копать?

Comment: `console.log($);` - ?

Answer (score 1):

На сайте не подключен Jquery, подключите и все должно работать.